# What to do with multiple Android apps that share about 90% of source code?

Tags: android

I have a public transport app for one country and I want to create a separate app for another country. Most of the code will be shared, but I need some classes to have different implementations for example TransitProvider.

Is it possible to share code using Android Library Project? Can I do the following?

1. Have TransitProvider (that extends
   AbstractTransitProvider) in the
   library project. The class has methods left unimplemented.
2. In application project > AndroidManifest.xml I have different package name than in library's manifest. I have also TransitProvider in this project, that is in the same package as the library's TransitProvider.
3. When I use TP in library project code, the implementation from app. project should be used (ie application project's TP overrides library's TP).

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to share code using Android Library Project?

Yes. That is the primary purpose of a library project. If you do not need Android resources, you can also use an ordinary JAR, created in a separate project.

> Can I do the following?

You cannot have the same class (in the same package) defined in two places, if I understand your proposed steps properly.

You should:

1. Define `AbstractTransitProvider` in the library project or JAR
2. Optionally have one or more concrete implementations of `AbstractTransitProvider`, for straight-up reuse, in the library project or JAR
3. Apps using the library project or JAR can have their own concrete implementations of `AbstractTransitProvider`, in their own Java packages, in addition to using any concrete implementations supplied by the library project or JAR

Comment: Thanks for answer. Most of the resources will be common for my apps, so I'll be using library project. I need to do something like this from library project's Activity: `Journey result = new TransitProvider().findJourney();` How can I make sure, that the application project's `TransitProvider` implementation is used?

Comment: @fhucho: "How can I make sure, that the application project's TransitProvider implementation is used?" -- by only having one class named `TransitProvider`. Do not have a class named `TransitProvider` in the library project. Put the common code in `AbstractTransitProvider` in the library project (and/or other utility classes), and the custom implementation in `TransitProvider` in the application project.

Comment: But the library project doesn't seem to know about the TransitProvider  that is located in app project. App can use classes from lib but not the other way around I think.

Comment: @fhucho: "But the library project doesn't seem to know about the TransitProvider that is located in app project." -- it should not need to. The library knows about `AbstractTransitProvider`, and so long as `TransitProvider` extends `AbstractTransitProvider`, that's all that matters.

Comment: I have `new TransitProvider()` in lib > MainActivity. Compiler says "TransitProvider cannot be resolved to a type" and neither app or lib can be built.

Comment: @fhucho: "I have new TransitProvider() in lib > MainActivity" -- I have no idea what this means. If you are saying that `MainActivity` exists in the *library*, and it is the one trying to call `new TransitProvider()`, that is not going to work. The code that calls `new TransitProvider()` needs to be in the app, not the library. For example, `MainActivity` could be abstract, requiring a `getTransitProvider()` method. The app would extend `MainActivity` supplying that method implementation, and the manifest would point to the app's `MainActivity` subclass.

Comment: Yes, every Activity is in the library. Only about 3 classes are app-specific.

Comment: The problem is that my code could get quite messy using this approach. So maybe a more suitable solution is to have only one project with a my.package.appspecific subpackage. In this subpackage I would have app-specific classes. Some script would switch between apps by changing content of appspecific subpackage and by changing the package name in manifest.

Comment: @fhucho: That seems messier to me, but it's your code. Bear in mind that the pattern I described is a fairly common one in Java, particularly Android. You supply concrete implementations of interfaces and abstract classes all of the time (`OnClickListener`, `ServiceConnection`, `Runnable`, etc.) triggered by callbacks you override in an Activity subclass (`onCreate()`, `onListItemClick()`, etc.).